# Setting Hyperlink and Image URL from database -SQL/VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table which will always just have 3 rows in it which are updated each week. I need to read them and populate 3 ImageUrl's and 3 associated Hyperlinks. However, i'm getting the error :

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: hyperlink1
```

I'm probably way off here as I'm still learning but here we go.. I select them simply with..

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT hyperlink As hyperlink1 WHERE productNo=1),
    (SELECT imageUrl As imageUrl1 WHERE productNo=1),
    (SELECT hyperlink As hyperlink2 WHERE productNo=2),
    (SELECT imageUrl As imageUrl2 WHERE productNo=2),
    (SELECT hyperlink As hyperlink3  WHERE productNo=3),
    (SELECT imageUrl As imageUrl3 WHERE productNo=3)
```

FROM tblAmazonProducts 
END

Then the VB Code..

```vb
    Public Function GetAmazonProducts()
        Dim DBConnectAm As New DBConn
        Using db As DbConnection = DBConnectAm.Conn("DBConnectionString")
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnectAm.Command(db, "SelectAmazonProducts")
            'cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("productNo", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = productNo
            db.Open()
            Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                hypAmazonProduct1.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink1")
                imghypAmazonProduct1.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl1")
                hypAmazonProduct2.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink2")
                imghypAmazonProduct2.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl2")
                hypAmazonProduct3.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink3")
                imghypAmazonProduct3.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl3")
            DR.Close()
            DR = Nothing
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            db.Dispose()
            db.Close()
        End Using
   End Function
```

Comment: It looks like you will end up with the product data from the last row in the reader in all of your product variables. Probably not what you want. Instead of a loop, read the first row and fill up Product1 data. Read the second row and fill up Product2 data. Read the third row and fill up Product3 data.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Thanks, that makes sense. I took the loop out but now get System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: Did you replace the loop with 3 individual DR.Read statements, one for each of the 3 rows to retrieve?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson yes, i dont need the productNo so I changed the select to SELECT hyperlink, imageurl FROM tblAmazonProducts and then did all the DR's above.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and show your current code. Or start a new question. It's hard to see the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I've edited the question. Many thanks again.

Comment: You're never calling DR.Read. You have to call it before you try to access a row. You need to call it before trying to fill up the 2 Product1 variables. Again before trying to fill up the 2 Product2 variables and once more before trying to fill up the 2 Product3 variables.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Thanks,and many thanks for your help.  I've just figured it out. I put the Do While back in and then jiggled the SELECT statement around in each line to look like this: (SELECT hyperlink FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=1)As hyperlink1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the Do While back in and then jiggled the SELECT statement around in each line to look like this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT hyperlink FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=1)As hyperlink1,
    (SELECT imageUrl FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=1) As imageUrl1,
    (SELECT hyperlink FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=2) As hyperlink2,
    (SELECT imageUrl FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=2) As imageUrl2,
    (SELECT hyperlink FROM tblAmazonProducts  WHERE productNo=3) As hyperlink3,
    (SELECT imageUrl FROM tblAmazonProducts WHERE productNo=3) As imageUrl3
```

VB..

```vb
    Dim DBConnectAm As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnectAm.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnectAm.Command(db, "SelectAmazonProducts")
        'cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("productNo", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = productNo
        db.Open()
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While DR.Read
            hypAmazonProduct1.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink1")
            imghypAmazonProduct1.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl1")
            hypAmazonProduct2.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink2")
            imghypAmazonProduct2.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl2")
            hypAmazonProduct3.navigateurl=DR("hyperlink3")
            imghypAmazonProduct3.ImageUrl=DR("imageUrl3")
        End While
        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: I just added a language tag to your answer to get rid of the red. <!-- language: vb.net --> The default parser messes up when you have a comment on a separate line.